# Setting an Indices and Vertices array openGL ES

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, indices

I am working on an .obj loader for my app, and to do so, i set an indices array and a vertices array and init them on runtime.

This is how the structs are defined:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;

typedef struct {
    GLuint  v1;
    GLuint  v2;
    GLuint  v3;
} Face3D;
```

and this is how the arrays are in the .h file:

```
Vertex* VerticesArr;
Face3D* Faces;
```

But when i init them, i see nothing on my screen, as opposed to using this way:

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1},{0,0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1},{0,0}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1},{0,0}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1},{0,0}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

by using these const arrays, i get the drawing on the screen.

My question is, is using the indices and vertices array as i do is even possible?
I believe it is, it just seems to be wrong.

This is how i setup my VBO's on both ways presented earlier:

```
- (void)setupVBOs {

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VerticesArr), VerticesArr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Faces), Faces, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

and the way i'm using draw elements:

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, sizeof(Faces)/sizeof(Faces[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I do check that both arrays are being init as they should, and they do.

This is how i allocate space for them:

```
// Allocate space for the Vertices array
NSLog(@"Size of vertice is: %lu",sizeof(Vertex));
VerticesArr = (Vertex*)(malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * vertexCombinations.count));
// Allocate space for the Faces
NSLog(@"Size of face is: %lu",sizeof(Face3D));
Faces = (Face3D*)(malloc(sizeof(Face3D)*faceCount));
```

Answer (score 2):

First problem I see is in this portion of the code:

```
- (void)setupVBOs {

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VerticesArr), VerticesArr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Faces), Faces, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

When you create the constant array `sizeof(Faces)` will return the size of your array, but when you dynamically allocate them then `sizeof(Faces)` will be the size of a pointer (usually 4 bytes).  The second problem I see is that during the static allocation your indecies is `GLUByte` but in `Face3D` they are `GLUInt`.  Not sure if that's a problem, but it seems like it could be.

Comment: You were right about the size of `Faces`, same goes for size of `VerticesArr`... now i get drawings, but only like half a model. got any tips about where to start debugging this?

Comment: How did you solve this? Are you just using the vertex count instead of sizeof(VerticesArr)?

Answer (score 1):

Potential issues:

1) C does not guarantee tight packing of structs. So e.g. the compiler might look at your `Face3D`, spot that it's 12 bytes long and decide to pad it to 16 bytes — each struct will have four unused bytes at the end because doing so is likely to make reading individual structs faster. Similarly it reserves the right to pad between individual items in the struct. You're using natively-sized units so padding isn't necessarily likely but your compiler reserves the right to add it and relying on tight packing means relying on undefined behaviour.

2) `sizeof(Faces)/sizeof(Faces[0])` — `sizeof(struct Face3D)` is a very different quantity from `sizeof(GLuint)` so even if your structs are tightly packed this is a difference between your two pieces of code.

You could check whether `sizeof(struct Face3D) == sizeof(GLuint)*3` and the equivalent test elsewhere at runtime. If so then you can pass the struct directly to `glBufferData`. If not then you could possibly just pass an appropriate stride with `glVertexAttribPointer` depending on the exact padding but more likely you're going to need explicitly to serialise to an unstructured array for OpenGL's benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer tommy, do you suggest i should just create an array of `GLuint` for the indices? meaning without using the `Face3D` struct and just adding them one after the other? will openGL know how to separate the x,y,z? i mean just going 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: And btw, i just checked and indeed `sizeof(struct Face3D) == sizeof(GLuint)*3`, but now i get only half of the obj drawn. This is not easy to deal with!

Comment: To be entirely safe, you should deserialise the structured data to raw arrays for OpenGL's benefit. Just write your own wrapper for `glBufferData` that `malloc`s an appropriate sized array, iterates through the structs to fill the array, then posts the array via `glBufferData` itself.